# List and Put method

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm new to django-framework. I'm trying to list and create two models at the same time. But I'm unable to bring the data of the two models in a single json

**models.py**

```
class User(models.Model):
    id=models.CharField(max_length=9,primary_key=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ActivityPeriod(models.Model):
    tz=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    start_time=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    end_time=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    activityperiod2user=models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='activityperiods', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.activityperiod2user)
```

**views.py**

```
class CustomApiView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.CustomSerializer
```

**serializers.py**

```
class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=models.User
        fields=("__all__")

class CustomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    activitydata=CustomUserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model=models.User
        fields=('name','activitydata')
```

Comment: why do both serializers have `User` as model? Read [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) it shows exactly the same as what you're trying to do (`Album` is your `User` and `Track` is your `ActivityPeriod`).

Comment: Note that the relationship from user to activity period is named `activityperiods` in your model, not `activitydata`.